# Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm following [this link](http://www.justinmichaels.net/using-jquery-datatables-with-asp-net-mvc-for-serverside-filtering-sorting-and-paging) to implement server side pagination in jquery datatable.

I have index view which load partial view with jquery data table. This partial view calls asp.net-mvc controller and return json data which should be injected into jquery datatable.  But on initial render of my index view I'm getting following error

```
DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable
```

so I tried to add into partial view where jquery datatable is initialized

```
 "bRetrieve": true,
```

but that not helped.

partial view jq. data table initialization looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-table').dataTable({
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/MyController/MyAction",
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "String A" },
            { "mDataProp": "String B" },           
            { "mDataProp": "String C" }],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                var birthday = new Date(parseInt(aData.Birthday.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html(birthday.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + birthday.getDate() + "/" + birthday.getFullYear());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I'm missing here?

Update:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(JQueryDataTablesModel model)
{
    int totalRecordCount;
    int searchRecordCount;    
    var data = GetMyData(model.iDisplayStart, model.iDisplayLength, model.GetSortedColumns(),
                out totalRecordCount, out searchRecordCount, model.sSearch);

  return Json(new JQueryDataTablesResponse<MyObject>(data, totalRecordCount, searchRecordCount, model.sEcho));          
  }
```

Comment: can we see the code of this call "sAjaxSource": "/MyController/MyAction" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding option:
`"destroy": true`.